# Several widgets using XCode Storyboard (or "doing it wrong")?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have started a new Storyboard (iPad) based XCode project that should have a UI basically like this:

1. One screen displays results coming in from the network fullscreen with a navigation bar at the top.
2. The end-user can switch to another screen with nav controller from (1) to a screen that should contain a table listing a few actors + some additional widgets.

The networking code already works fine, but I'm having problems interacting with the data. I have created the following UI in XCode:

[image: storyboard creation attempt]

I can't get the `UITableView` on screen 2 to have a proper `UITableViewController` without being forced into a full-screen situation with *only* the `UITableView` in screen 2.

- Can I specify a `UITableViewController` (or indeed any kind of `*Controller` to widgets embedded in a view in this way?
- Alternatively: is there a preferred other way of handling UI's like this using Storyboards?
- Am I just pushing Storyboards too far and should revert to 'nibs'/programmatic creation?

**Edit** @jrturton's answer is correct<strike>, a little picture to complement his additional specification:</strike>

[image]

**Edit** Ops, danger! You must not drag to the parent **`View`**, you must ensure that you drag to the parent's `View` **`Controller`**, otherwise [bad things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785479/failing-to-properly-declare-implement-uitableviewdatasource-methods) can happen:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a UITableViewController. As you've found, this defaults to using the whole of its view (e.g the full screen) as the table - in fact, the view property of a table view controller *is* the table view.

No need to worry, though - simply declare that your view controller conforms to the UITableView delegate and datasource protocols, connect the tableView's datasource and delegate methods to the view controller, and implement the methods. UITableViewController isn't special in that regard - any object can do this.

You may also want to define a table view outlet on your view controller and connect this to the table view. It is often needed to talk to the table view outside of the delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: You're right! (After one has right-clicked and dragged the `dataStore` outlet to the parent view)

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention connecting the outlets. I'll update the answer.